# Why does the selected build configuration not get applied to the project file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, configuration, msbuild

This may be a noobish question but here I go anyway.

So in VS I have a project whose build configuration I changed from Debug|AnyCpu to Release|AnyCpu.

Now this all works good and fine and when I build the project via VS this configuration is also used in the build process.

however I am also using the msbuild.exe in order to build the project via command sometimes and the problem is no matter what I do I can not change the

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```

element of the project via VS. So setting the build configuration does only seem to work for VS and I bascially have to manually add this in the project file so that the msbuild.exe uses the correct build configuration.

Any Idea how I can change it in VS so the change also alters the project file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change it explicitly. This string is "default configuration" for msbuild and VS - if no $(Configuration) value specified - set it to Debug.

If you want to build release configuration using msbuild you may want to specify configuration property or platform architecture in command line explicitly:

```
msbuild.exe myProject.csproj /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Comment: By default what configuration does build takes if nothing is mentioned in csproj ?

Comment: you build will fail if there will be no Configuration and Platform at all, so csproj always has unconditional defaults in the first PropertyGroup
```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
 <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```